# Prove that if the degree of the polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $m$ and $n$ be integers greater than $2$, and let $A$ and $B$ be non-constant polynomials with complex coefficients, at least one of which has a degree greater than $1$. Prove that if the degree of the polynomial $A^m-B^n$ is less than $\min(m,n)$, then $A^m=B^n$.

This conclusion is a consequence of the following version of the Mason-Stothers theorem:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mason-Stothers_theorem

but are there any other solutions?